# Web application client server

Tags: c#

I want to create a client/server web application.  The client and server can exchange data back and forth.  When i say data i mean like a number, for example (0,8,7...), so everytime a client presses a button it sends a number to the server and the server send an acknowledgement back to client.  The cleint side i want to put it on the internet so you can access the server from a browser.

Is silverlight socket the way to go?  I know theres port restrictions but im planning on using my personal router to open up the ports.  Or is socket only for local connections???

Comment: missing all relevant information to answer it. There are a great many solutions to the problem depending on the parameters you did not define (security, timing behavior etc.).

Comment: Perhaps this person just has no idea where to start, and therefore can't ask the question more specifically.

Comment: Then, perhaps, the OP should say so to start with? Explicitely?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you just have no idea where to start, I'd say you should start by learning about  [WCF (Windows Communication Foundation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx).  Obviously, start with the beginner's guide.  There are some nice introductory videos there that should get you going.

Comment: I would second that. For anything except hard realt time stuff (MMORPG style, financial trading style; WCF is a good way to go.

Comment: @TomTom do you have a reference for your assertion? I thought that WCF was suitable even for real time performance critical apps, as the ones I built at work (with WCF)

Comment: WCF mostly is TCP based. TCP has problems with packet loss. So, if you do stuff like transfer large blobs they may hang occasionally. Common knowledge. Whether or not this is acceptable depends, but hard real time stuff may want to use it's own lower level protocol. This is why audio / video is not sent via TCP.

Answer (score 0):

If there is such a thing as Silverlight sockets, you can use them. I'd rather use WCF. Sockets aren't restricted to local connections, but you should be aware that using ports different from 80 in Web applications can restrict some user from accessing your them.

I would like to add that sockets aren't the fastest local connections, but are the base of almost all inter-machine communication.