# Visual studio web application

Tags: c#, silverlight

I want to create a web application using visual studio to implement a client/server.  The server program will be a simple console application that waits for a connection from the client.  The client will be a web application.  I have look at Silverlight but that would require the client side to download the silverlight plug-in and could be restricted.

Whats a different approach to this that would require minimal to no installation on the client side??

Comment: You have asked a lot of questions, yet have not once voted or accepted any answers. Also, your question does not seem to make sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web application client server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010421/web-application-client-server)

Answer (score 1):

You got the terminology wrong.. If you want the user to use a web browser in order to use your application (which is the case for Silverlight) - and you want to use c# (without making the user install anything else)- go with either ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC.

If you want the client to be a winform/WPF application, sending requests to a server - go with WCF on the server side.

If you're not sure what you want, please make it a new question of itself.

Comment: using asp.net or asp.net mvc, would that require the user to install anything such as .NET framework or anytin when they go on a web browser to use it?